# Bootstrap 3: How do I force columns to be same height and align buttons to bottom

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two columns that contain text and a button after the text. The text can be quite long or rather short so the columns will have a different height. I would like the columns to be the same height and align the buttons at the bottom. Here is a sample of what my HTML looks like:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

  <div class="col-sm-6 outer">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 inner">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h4>Content content content content content</h4>
        <button class="btn btn-default">Text</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6 outer">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 inner">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h4>Content content content content content content content content content</h4>
        <button class="btn btn-default">Text</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Live code:

http://www.bootply.com/114596

Is there any way of doing this without Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is to add `overflow:auto;`

**CSS**

```
h4{
  height:200px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So obvious now that I see it.